# Does there exist a Banach space $E$ with $L(E)$ separable?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

The title says it all. Does there exist a (separable, infinite-dimensional) Banach space $E$ with the normed space $L(E)$ of bounded, linear operators thereon separable?

Comment: Argyros & Haydon gave an example of an infinite-dimensional Banach spaces $E$ such that every operator is of the form compact + scalar.  Would that imply that $L(E)$ is separable? https://doi.org/10.1007/s11511-011-0058-y

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Why the question mark?

Comment: @YemonChoi ... Because Parschalien should think about it.  This is also why it was a comment and not an answer.